# MySQL Error: 1054 Unkown column in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql, where-clause, mysql-error-1054

I am creating a view with the query shown below:

```
create view v2 as
(select * from appearance a
where exists (
    select p.id from photo p, photographer u, person s
    where p.takenBy = u.id
    and u.id = s.id
    and a.isShownIn = p.id
    and s.name = 'Fred'
    )
);
```

The appearance table has 2 columns 'shows' and 'isShownIn' but when i try to insert in the view, it gives me error as Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.isShownIn' in 'where clause'

While browsing over this I cam over that I am mistaking over alias, but everything looks OK to me, could anyone please point out where could be the error?

Thanks!

Comment: a isn't referenced in you subquery.    does the query itself run?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: I am using MySQL workbench 5.2 CE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to insert in a view created in that way. Only certain views are updateable. In your specific case, you should just insert into `appearance` table, since your view is just a selection from that table.

For limitations for updateable views, check [this](http://A%20subquery%20in%20the%20WHERE%20clause%20that%20refers%20to%20a%20table%20in%20the%20FROM%20clause) out. Your view has this problem: "A subquery in the WHERE clause that refers to a table in the FROM clause"

Like @Umbrella suggested, you can use join instead of exists, and in that way, you would avoid inner query, and you might have updateable view, but I really think that there is no need to insert into that view, because you will have the same effect by just inserting into `appearance` table.

Comment: "The appearance table has 2 columns 'shows' and 'isShownIn' but when i try to insert in the view, it gives me error as Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'a.isShownIn' in 'where clause'"...he says: "but when i try to insert in the view"

Comment: Wow, I really did miss something!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Inserting the appearance table won't update the view, right? So what is the way one should do that?

Comment: your insert in the table will be immediately reflected on view...view is just a "saved query". Here are some basics: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_(database) ... just try it and you will see that it works.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using `exists()`?  Why not just join them...

```
create view v2 as
select a.* 
from appearance a, photo p, photographer u, person s
where a.isShownIn = p.id
  and p.takenBy = u.id
  and u.id = s.id
  and s.name = 'Fred'
```